# Edit text value in React array using props and state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

In trying to learn React, I’m confused on how to handle this situation. Bare in mind I’m still kinda new to scripting languages.

I want to be able to click ‘edit’ and have a text box show up where the ‘name’ is next to the edit button and then proceed to edit the text. I cannot figure out how to get the value of the text I’m clicking on though. I know how to do it with a for loop but I’m trying to do with the ‘react way’ (using props and state). Is that doable?

```
handleEdit: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var i = e.target.value; //index in the array
        var friendsCopy = this.state.friendsArray;
        console.log('SPACE.');
        console.log(/*the text of the value in the array*/);
}
```

Everything I've tried has returned `undefined` or nothing at all (an empty line).
I've tried using `data-`attributes, referring directly to the value (`friendsCopy[e.text]`) and other ways. I know I'm not getting something and I've read the documentation but I can't seem to put it together.

https://jsfiddle.net/nckdls/69z2wepo/54502/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wfn0eqtk/

Generally your code was correct, the missing piece was providing the index of the friend that was being edited. Since you already had a ShowList component, I just modified it to bind the click callback with the index of the item being edited, and triggering that to the passed in prop.

```
triggerEdit: function(index, e) {
    this.props.handleEdit(index, e)
},

<button onClick={this.triggerEdit.bind(this, index)}>
```

Finally, I modified your `handleEdit` function in the parent component to accept the new index parameter, access the `friendsCopy` array, and console.log the result.

```
handleEdit: function(editingIndex, e){
    var friendsCopy = this.state.friendsArray;
    var editingFriend = friendsCopy[editingIndex];
    console.log(editingFriend);
},
```

Bind Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Bind is used to change the scope (the value of `this`) to a function, but it can also be used to pass additional parameters. In this case the parameters are injected before other arguments are passed to the bound function.

Comment: Ahh!! I missed feeding the index to the button! Thanks for pointing that out! I am able to get the same result though by simply adding `value={index}` to the edit button and calling `friendsCopy[i]`. Is the way you provided better would you say? Mainly because you're using `bind`. From what I've read `bind` is the way to go about editing or retrieving objects in React.

Comment: A couple of problems with `value`: 1) It makes you access the DOM API to get the value off of the element. 2) It works so long as this is a button. 3) It only supports stringifiable values. I prefer `bind` because it lets me pass in an arbitrary number of arguments, as well as any type

Comment: ^that makes sense. I'll use `bind`. much appreciated